# Minimal distance k-subset to x-axis

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

Let `A` is `2D`-point set, `|A| = n`.

Let `OX = {point: point.y = 0}` (x-axis).

I need to find `R = min_{A_k from set of all k-subsets A} (max_{a from A_k} distance(a,OX))`,

`k = const, 1 <= k <= n`.

Thank you for any help!

P.s. I can use `R` with accuracy of `1e-3` and `a` from `A` from integer plane, `a.x <=1000`, `a.y <= 1000`.

Comment: OX as you've described it is the y axis, not x.  Also, your notation for R is very hard to grok in typewriter font. Can you write it out in words?

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-calculate `distance(a,OX)` for every `a` in `A`.

For now, let's assume that `A` is sorted with respect to `distance(a,OX)`. Then, given the (also sorted) subset `A_k`, `max_{a from A_k} distance(a,OX)` is clearly the last element's distance. Now we need to find the subset `A_k` where the last element is minimal. Obviously, this is the subset that begins at the first element and ends at the `k`-th element. Hence, `R` is the `k`-th smallest distance value in `A`. This can be found with QuickSelect in `O(n)`.